# java.net.UnknownHostException in WildFly start

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm getting the following error when I start up a Java server process (WildFly application server):

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy01.phx2.fedoraproject.org: Name or service not known
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1501)
```

The server is not harmed by this error,  but it bothers me to have this error in the logs. It is something related with my environment. Indeed, the problem happens no matter which version of the server and on any location of my file system.

I have checked in /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf but I really don't have idea where the "proxy01.phx2.fedoraproject.org" comes from.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: May i ask if you are using Ansible to provision the environment?

Comment: No I'm not using Ansible to install WildFly. It's a local (unzipped) installation.

Comment: I agree with @VaradharajanDamotharan - all Google hits for `proxy01.phx2.fedoraproject.org` are related to Ansible.  Can you describe your environment a bit more?